# Regarding alternative to interfaces and acessing with static imorts

Tags: java

I was going through a research in which I dont want to store the constants in the interface itself, so I was looking for alternatives like enums but another approach I have found is that ....t instead of using an interface, use a final class with a private constructor. (Making it impossible to instantiate or subclass the class, sending a strong message that it doesn't contain non-static functionality/data. and we can also take the advantage of static import in that case

```
Public final class KittenConstants
{
    private KittenConstants() {}

    public static final String KITTEN_SOUND = "meow";
    public static final double KITTEN_CUTENESS_FACTOR = 1;
}
```

two independent things. 1: use static imports instead of abusing inheritance. 2: If you must have a constants repository, make it a final class instead of an interface . Please advise is this approach is correct..!!

To avoid some pitfalls of the constant interface (because you can't prevent people from implementing it), a proper class with a private constructor should be preferred (example borrowed from Wikipedia):

```
public final class Constants {

private Constants() {
    // restrict instantiation
}

public static final double PI = 3.14159;
public static final double PLANCK_CONSTANT = 6.62606896e-34;
}
```

And to access the constants without having to fully qualify them (i.e. without having to prefix them with the class name), use a static import (since Java 5):

```
import static Constants.PLANCK_CONSTANT;
import static Constants.PI;

public class Calculations {

    public double getReducedPlanckConstant() {
        return PLANCK_CONSTANT / (2 * PI);
    }
}
```

Please show how we can do same ting with enum also..!

Comment: What's the reason for not using Enums?

Comment: @Jon Lin.. dude could you please convert my second example into enum and show how the class can aceess the constants of enum that will  be a great help to understand..!!

Comment: @w4rumy  could you please convert my second example into enum and show how the class can aceess the constants of enum that will be a great help to understand

Comment: @Crazy4Java See my answer for how to do this an enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't do that with an `enum`.  An enum defines a set of related constants *with the same type*.

What you have in the `KittenConstants` case is a set of constants with fundamentally different types.  This doesn't fit the `enum` model.  (If you change the problem a bit; e.g. by generalizing over different kinds of SFA, you can make it fit ... as @Bohemian does ... but if that's not what you are trying to achieve, `enum` is not the right solution.)

What you have in the `Constants` case is a bunch of named floating point constants that you want to use as values.  (All the same type ... which helps!)  Now you could declare them as an `enum` as follows:

```
    public enum Constants {
        PLANCK_CONSTANT(6.62606896e-34),
        PI(3.14.59);

        public final double value;

        Constants(double value) {this.value = value);
    }
```

The snag is that you need to use ".value" to access each named constant's numeric value; e.g.

```
    import static Constants.*;
    ....
    public double getReducedPlanckConstant() {
        return PLANCK_CONSTANT.value / (2 * PI.value);
    }
```

.... which is kind of ugly, and I don't think there is any way around the ugliness.

Bottom line - enums are not an ideal replacement for *all* kinds of constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your "constants" via an enum:

```
public enum Animal {
    Kitten("meow", 1),
    Puppy("woof", 2);

    private final String sound;
    private final double cuteness;

    Animal (String sound, double cuteness) {
        this.sound = sound;
        this.cuteness = cuteness;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public double getCuteness() {
        return cuteness;
    }
}
```

To use:

```
String sound = Animal.Kitten.getSound();
double cuteness = Animal.Kitten.getCuteness();
```